# How to incorporate a header-only library that uses CMake in a project that does not use CMake but uses make only?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I'm looking at the most idiomatic way to approach the following problem. I have a project A that wants to use a header-only library B. Project A uses a complex Makefile to build, where library B relies on its clients to configure it in the build step step using cmake.

I dont want to have to convert project A to use Cmake (its cross platform with many other dependencies). Since library B is header-only, I can't build it separately and later link to it separately during the build process of A. Whats the most idiomatic way to resolving this (without changing project A's entire build project to first use CMake) ?

Comment: What sort of configuration does a header only library need ?  Usually you would just set your include path and start using it.  If it really does need configuring create a new project just to configure it, then add it's path to your real projects include path.

Comment: There are plenty of options; what have you tried? You can be as simple as running `cmake` with the `Makefile` generator and simply recursing into it, or even just adding a `-I` to Library B's public directory (assuming Library B doesn't need any headers to be configured as part of the configuration step). If the dependency Library B is simply enough, you can drop the entire build-system even and rely on a static copy of the headers (which, being header-only, would work)

Comment: @Richard Critten: The header-only library has a choice of what exact-number types to use for example - it can use its own internal exact number implementation, or use a thirdparty exact number implementation. Based on that, CMake  would be defining macros in the final header files.

Comment: @Human-Compiler your assumption is precisely the reason i can't simply include it - see my comment above (header files are also generated in the configuration step)

Comment: I'm confused, why would headers being generated as part of the _configuration step_ pose a problem with my first suggestion of running `cmake` with the `Makefile` generator and including the Makefile hierarchy? That would introduce the target for Library B into Makefile's ecosystem so you can have a proper target-dependency from within Make -- which will allow you to use the generated sources. This can be done either as a pre-process step before Make, or even as a custom target from within Make if you'd prefer (e.g. `cmake ...; cmake --build ...; cmake --build . --target install`)

Comment: The Cmake run may create a configured main header, the only one to be included for project A.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm looking at the most idiomatic way to approach the following problem. I have a project A that wants to use a header-only library B. Project A uses a complex Makefile to build, where library B relies on its clients to configure it in the build step step using cmake.

The most idiomatic way to approach the problem is to leave the projects separate.  That means that library B is an *external* dependency of library A, to be built and installed independently.  The build system for project A then only needs to discover or be told where to find the B headers.  That B is a header-only library doesn't really factor in.

Comment: I don't agree with this being idiomatic at all. In fact, it can be dangerous to use this approach in many cases. Consider the simple case of cross-compiling and off-target building. If you configured a header for some ARM device on an x86_64 system -- you probably don't want that installed in your system headers. Most often, it's more desirable for a build-system -- even if it's Makefile -- to wrap such a build so that the installation process goes to a staging area, rather than having users accidentally install to system

Comment: @Human-Compiler, it is absolutely the usual way of going about things when building for the host machine or other similar ones.  Or that is anyway my perspective informed by decades of experience.  Moreover, introducing cross compilation does not actually make a difference to the fundamentals.  What it does is change *where* one would choose to install library B -- into a cross destination, not the build host's main system.  It is by no means normal for a single-project cross build to build dependencies that are not included in a native build.

Comment: I install to a local prefix _even_ when working with multiple CMake projects. Wrangling misbehaving projects through `add_subdirectory` or `FetchContent` or (even worse) `ExternalProject` is too brittle and too full of "gotchas". Just going through the project's intended consumption method (pkg-config, `find_package`, etc.) is usually the most reliable option.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No need to be so defensive with the whole "decades of experience" quip . I was just trying to say that expecting clients of a large code-base to remember to install to the correct directory tends to lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs when cross-compiling. Basically, unless managed by _some tool somewhere_ -- whether it's the same build system (i.e. Makefile) or some external manager that coordinates them (script, or something else) -- you run the risk of user-errors occurring. The human factor is important to consider in such cases because it can waste time and money.